# copy constructors in structs: Do arrays get copied

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, assignment-operator

I have a question about the copy constructor behaviour in C++. I have a struct as follows:

```
struct Vec4
{
public:
   float elems[4];

};
```

Now if I do something like:

```
Vec4 copied = some_func(); // returns a Vec4 object
```

Will this perform a deep copy of the elms array or would it just copy the pointer address? I am thinking it should be the latter and an explicit copy constructor and assignment operator should be provided but am not sure.

I did a small test and it does what it is supposed to do but I am not sure if that is just an accident!

Comment: Yes, the array is copied by value.

Comment: "would it just copy the pointer address?" - there is no pointer to copy the address to.

Comment: The array is an array, not a pointer.

Comment: Think about it: where would that "address" go?  It would have to go in a pointer, but there is no pointer member in this struct.  This should also tell you what happens if you instead had `float *elems;` as a member, and used dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: something something you should still use `std::array<float, 4>` if you can (i.e. if you have a c++11 compiler)

Comment: Thanks! I thought perhaps internally this array degenerates to a pointer and it only copies the first address. Sorry for the confusion. I could use std::array but the places I have to deploy things to still have old compilers...

Comment: Also note that since you already defined the number of elements in your array, it is placed in the stack memory and thus no dynamic memory is allocated at all. default copy constructor will always work as expected in such cases.

Comment: @AndyReimann It's only on the stack if the `Vec4` is on the stack.

Comment: :) correct, what I wanted to say is that the default constructor will be completely sufficient here since the member variable is not initialized allocating dynamic memory...sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `elems` is a subobject of a `Vec4` object, so it gets copied along with the `Vec4`. There is no pointer to be copied. The array elements are literally embedded inside the `Vec4` object.

I find the terms deep- and shallow-copy a little misleading in C and C++. I think a better way to think about it is that a defaulted copy will not follow any levels of indirection (such as pointers). You can have a really "deep" object (lots of subobjects of subobjects and so on) where no indirection is involved and still the whole thing would be copied, yet we still call this a "shallow copy". If you need to follow any indirection, you need to implement a custom copy constructor that does a "deep copy".